Performance on SEARCH + FILTER on arango Views to use both ANALYZERS and FILTERS
Context :

Arango 3.12.1

inside a docker container

large collections (over 2m documents)

need to use analyzers

nested collections enterprise <-- legal_unit

use of edges
In my case I would need to use views with text_fr analyzers (go through accents, lower case, uppercase...) and also filter using edges.

for instance I have this query:

I am trying to filter the collection enterprise based on the linked legal_units with admin_status == 1

my collection legal_unit has an index on admin_status ( tho the  estimate selectivity is around 0 which is pretty strange because out of 2m documents 1m "1" and the second million has "3"

the link between legal_unit and enterprise is 1:1 tho i created a edge for simplicity :
unite_legale_de_l_entreprise


here in this case I don't have SEARCH statements ( I use a query builder, for fields that are enums I use filter , for the other fileds SEARCH ANALYZERS STARTS_WITH)




THE QUERY :
LET FILTER_UNITE_LEGALE = (
            FOR u IN vw_legal_unit
            SEARCH 1==1
            FILTER (u.admin_status == "1")
            RETURN u._id
        )

        FOR e0 IN unite_legale_de_l_entreprise
        FILTER e0._from IN FILTER_UNITE_LEGALE
        FOR e IN vw_enterprise
        SEARCH  1==1
        FILTER e._id == e0._to AND 1==1
        COLLECT WITH COUNT INTO length
        RETURN length

here is the explain of the query :
Query String (425 chars, cacheable: true):
 LET FILTER_UNITE_LEGALE = (
             FOR u IN vw_legal_unit
             SEARCH 1==1
             FILTER (u.admin_status == "1")
             RETURN u._id
         )
         FOR e0 IN unite_legale_de_l_entreprise
         FILTER e0._from IN FILTER_UNITE_LEGALE
         FOR e IN vw_enterprise
         SEARCH  1==1
         FILTER e._id == e0._to AND 1==1
         COLLECT WITH COUNT INTO length
         RETURN length

Execution plan:
 Id   NodeType            Par       Est.   Comment
  1   SingletonNode                    1   * ROOT
 18   SubqueryStartNode                1     - LET FILTER_UNITE_LEGALE = ( /* subquery begin */
  3   EnumerateViewNode          7695748       - FOR u IN vw_legal_unit SEARCH true   /* view query */
  4   CalculationNode            7695748         - LET #7 = (u.`admin_status` == "1")   /* simple expression */
  5   FilterNode                 7695748         - FILTER #7
  6   CalculationNode            7695748         - LET #8 = u.`_id`   /* attribute expression */
 19   SubqueryEndNode                  1         - RETURN  #8 ) /* subquery end */
 17   IndexNode             ✓         10     - FOR e0 IN unite_legale_de_l_entreprise   /* edge index scan, index only (projections: `_to`) */    LET #11 = e0.`_to`   
 12   EnumerateViewNode     ✓   21405490       - FOR e IN vw_enterprise SEARCH true   /* view query */
 13   CalculationNode       ✓   21405490         - LET #10 = ((e.`_id` == #11) && true)   /* simple expression */
 14   FilterNode            ✓   21405490         - FILTER #10
 15   CollectNode           ✓          1         - COLLECT AGGREGATE length = LENGTH()   /* count */
 16   ReturnNode                       1         - RETURN length

Indexes used:
 By   Name   Type   Collection                     Unique   Sparse   Cache   Selectivity   Fields        Stored values   Ranges
 17   edge   edge   unite_legale_de_l_entreprise   false    false    false       99.98 %   [ `_from` ]   [  ]            (e0.`_from` IN FILTER_UNITE_LEGALE)

Optimization rules applied:
 Id   Rule Name                                 Id   Rule Name                                 Id   Rule Name                        
  1   move-calculations-up                       5   use-indexes                                9   reduce-extraction-to-projection  
  2   move-filters-up                            6   remove-filter-covered-by-index            10   optimize-projections             
  3   move-calculations-up-2                     7   handle-arangosearch-views                 11   async-prefetch                   
  4   move-filters-up-2                          8   remove-unnecessary-calculations-2         12   splice-subqueries                

54 rule(s) executed, 1 plan(s) created, peak mem [b]: 0, exec time [s]: 0.00099

I guess since the selectivity estimate of admin_status is around 0 the optimizer decided not to use it ... tho, i dont understand why the selectivity would be around 0 for this index :
FOR doc IN unite_legale
COLLECT status = doc.admin_status WITH COUNT INTO count
RETURN { 
  "admin_status": status, 
  "count": count 
}

[
  {
    "admin_status": "1",
    "count": 1198532
  },
  {
    "admin_status": "3",
    "count": 942016
  }
]

{
  "cacheEnabled": false,
  "deduplicate": false,
  "estimates": true,
  "fields": [
    "admin_status"
  ],
  "figures": {
    "memory": 31846005,
    "cacheInUse": false,
    "cacheSize": 0,
    "cacheUsage": 0
  },
  "id": "unite_legale/583153",
  "name": "admin_status_legal_idx",
  "selectivityEstimate": 9.343401783094796e-7,
  "sparse": false,
  "type": "persistent",
  "unique": false
}

So here are my questions:
- Is my synthax for my use case the right way to do it ?
- is my index on admin_status broken ?
- how could I improve performances ?
I tried several indexing logic,
using the collection over the view
I'd like to use the vertex logic with views but the synthax logic still is a bit odd for me
